# Modify jquery script to use this.parent in appendTo() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using this jquery script to duplicate the first element inside a `<div>` with class `scoll-box`:

```
$(".scroll-box > *").first().clone().appendTo(".scroll-box");
```

I'd like to rewrite the `appendTo()` portion of the script to use a `$(this).parent` specification so the script can be run on multiple instances of the `.scroll-box` element.  How would I do this?

The original HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="scroll-box" class="scroll-box">
    <div>Line 1</div>
    <div>Line 2</div>
    <div>Line 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to a different element each time, the best thing to do is `.each`, in which `this` is one of the set of elements each time:

```
// for each .scroll-box
$(".scroll-box").each(function() {
    // clone first child and append to this .scoll-box
    $(this).children().first().clone().appendTo(this);
});
```

`.parent()` is not necessary this way, since `this` refers to a `.scoll-box` element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".scroll-box > *").each(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo($(this).parent());
});
```

Comment: This does not clone the element, so it will be moved.

Answer (score 0):

cache the selectors and use the `.parent()` method.

```
var el = $(".scroll-box > *");
var clone = el.first().clone();
el.parent().append(clone);
```